# Are RSM and RBFN essentially GLM?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, radial-basis

1. Is response surface methodology (RSM) the same as a generalized linear model (GLM) with quadratic terms and normal error distribution?
2. Is radial basis function network (RBFN) also the same as a generalized linear model (GLM) with several weighted radial basis functions and normal error distribution?

If the answer is 'Yes' to both questions, why did so many terms which essentially mean the same appear in literature?

Comment: How is response surface methodology RBF? I think that's just a typo but it may just hide some part of the question, so I am asking you to clarify. The general question at the end is all too easy to answer, unfortunately: because different people in different fields re-discover similar or identical ideas and/or perversely prefer their own terminology.

Comment: @NickCox It was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Well, response surface methodology is about *choosing good experimental designs* to fit the models rather than about how you fit them.

Comment: @Scortchi I agree, that's a part of RSM. I am referring to the regression part here.

Comment: The canonical regression would be fitting a full second-order model (quadratic terms & linear interactions) for normal means, but others aren't outside the scope of RSM.

Comment: Is chemistry synonymous with titration? No, and RSM is not synonymous with GLM. GLM refers to a technique, and RSM is a whole discipline of doing experimentation to find the best operating conditions.